# Is there any reason not to use auto_increment on an index for a database table?

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

I've inherited the task of maintaining a very poorly-coded e-commerce site and I'm working on refactoring a lot of the code and trying to fix ongoing bugs.

Every database insert (adding an item to cart, etc.) begins with a grab_new_id function which COUNTs the number of rows in the table, then, starting with that number, querys the database to find an unused index number. In addition to being terrible performance-wise (there are 40,000+ rows already, and indexes are regularly deleted, so sometimes it takes several seconds just to find a new id) this breaks regularly when two operations are preformed simultaneously, as two entries are added with duplicate id numbers.

This seems idiotic to me - why not just use auto-increment on the index field? I've tested it both ways, and adding rows to the table without specifying an index id is (obviously) many times faster. My question is: can anyone think of any reason the original programmer might have done this? Is there some school of thought where auto_increment is somehow considered bad form? Are there databases that don't have auto-increment capabilities?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've seen this before from someone that didn't know that feature existed. Definitely use the auto-increment feature.

Some people take the "roll your own" approach to everything, often because they haven't taken the time to see if that is an available feature or if someone else had already come up with it.  You'll often see crazy workarounds or poor performing/fragile code from these people.  Inheriting a bad database is no fun at all, good luck!

Comment: I once came across a function in C# called reverseBoolean.  All it did was accept a boolean as a parameter and return the reverse as a result.  It was overly complicated and just plain dumb.  All because the developer was unaware of the not operator.

Comment: I once saw code run on every single request made to a web app that forces all traffic to https if a flag was set in the database.  And it would fight with IIS's automatic handling on https and created an infinite redirection loop.  It was 2 days of awesomesauce before we found out what was going on.

Comment: WTFs FTW! Thats what I figured... just wanted to see if I might be missing something, or if there was some hidden reason for this function.

Answer (score 5):

Well Oracle has sequences but not auto-generated ids as I understand it. However, usually this kind of stuff is done by devs who don't understand database programming and who hate to see gaps in the data (as you get from rollbacks). There are also people who like to create the id, so they have it available beforhand to use for child tables, but most databases with autogenerated ids also have a way to return that id to the user at the time of creation.

Answer (score 3):

The only issue I found partially reasonable (but totally avoidable!) against auto_inc fields is that some backup tools by default include auto_inc values into table definition even if you don't include data into a db dump that may be inconvenient.

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the specific situation, there are clearly many reasons for not using consecutive numbers as a primary key.

However, under the given that I *do* want consecutive numbers as a primary key, I see no reason not to use the built in `auto_increment` functionality MySQL offers

Answer (score 1):

They may just have been inexperienced and unfamiliar with auto increment.  One reason I can think of, but doesn't necessarily make much sense, is that it is difficult (not impossible) to copy data from one environment to another when using auto increment id's.

For this reason, I have used sequential Guids as my primary key before for ease of transitioning data, but counting the rows to populate the ID is a bit of a [WTF](http://thedailywtf.com/).

Answer (score 1):

It was probably done that way for historical reasons; i.e. earlier versions didn't have autoinc variables.  I've written code that uses manual autoinc fields on databases that don't support autoinc types, but my code wasn't quite as inefficient as pulling a count().

One issue with using autoinc fields as a primary key is that moving records in and out of tables may result in the primary key changing.  So, I'd recommend designing in a "LegacyID" field up front that can be used as future storage for the primary key for times when you are moving records in and out of the table.

Answer (score 1):

Two things to watch for:

1.Your RDBMS intelligently sets the auto-increment value upon restart. Our engineers were rolling their own auto-increment key to get around the auto-increment field  jumping by an order of 100000s whenever the server restarted. However, at some point Sybase added an option to set the size of the auto-increment.

2.The other place where auto-increment can get nasty is if you are replicating databases and are using a master-master configuration. If you write on both databases (NOT ADVISED), you can run into identity-collision.

I doubt either of these were the case, but things to be aware of.

Answer (score 0):

I could see if the ids were generated on the client and pushed into the database, this is common practice when speed is necessary, but what you discribed seems over the top and unnecessary. Remove it and start an auto incrementing id.